# Regular Expression to exclude a string?

Tags: regex

I have a regular expression that runs through html tags and grabs  values.
I currently have this to grab all values within the  tag.

```
<title\b[^>]*>(.*\s?)</title>
```

It works perfectly. So if I have a bunch of pages that have titles:

```
<title>Index</title>

<title>Artwork</title>

<title>Theory</title>
```

The values returned are:
**Index**,
**Artwork**,
**Theory**

How can I make this regular expression ignore all  tags with the value Theory inside them?

Thanks in Advance

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454

Comment: Any particular reason you want to do this with only a regular expression?  It's really not very well suited for parsing HTML.

Comment: Yes there is a very particular reason. I just said html to keep it simple but it's really for a program that grabs XML data and inserts it into a database.

Comment: The question above doesn't exactly get me where I need to be,

Comment: The person asking this question wants to exclude tags with certain attributes - while I'm looking to exclude values with certain attributes within the tags themselves. Same logic but different expressions.

Comment: Parse the XML, you will be much better off. What language?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A basic look around [would probably handle that](https://regexr.com/609l6).

```
<title\b[^>]*>(((?!Juju - Search Results).)*)(.*\s?)<\/title>
```

Comment: That's a nice little program you have there but on my end there is no execute button to test.

Comment: I've tested the above code and it still didn't work. Let's say for instance instead of the value Theory - I want to ignore the value "Juju - Search Results". The regex can even exclude values that begin with the first 4 words without even being concerned with spaces.

Comment: Not sure I understand what you're getting at.  I've updated the example with the regEx that should handle the case you mentioned.

Comment: I had to switch the parentheses around and remove the last set of brackets and * but works like a charm!!

Comment: Just out of curiosity, can you post your final pattern?

Comment: I've updated my code and the link. I was missing an escape on the forward slash in the closing title element.